# how do I add custom function to zepto?

Tags: zepto

New to zepto (and honestly, far from a jQuery-whiz), 
I want to add a custom function.

This is my attempts so far:

```
//define..
$.fn.doSearch = function() { 
  alert(this.parentNode.html());
  //now xhr..
}
//assign..
$('#resetBtn').click( function (e) {$(this).doSearch()});
```

and

```
//define
<script type="text/ja..
function doSearch(obj) {
  alert('Ugly way but here I am');
}

//assign..
$('#resetBtn').click( function (e) {window.doSearch()});
```

And neither works.. I'd rather go the first route, aware that .fn isn't listed in the zepto-docs.

regards,

//t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, now I have

```
//define
var myFunc = {
  doSearch: function(obj) {
    //just check obj is ok.
    alert($(obj.parentNode).html());
  }
}
//correct way to extend zepto?
$.extend($,myFunc);

//assign...
$('#searchBtn').click( function (e) {$(this).doSearch(this)});
```

is this the way to go?

Comment: In Jquery if you do $.fn.myFunc, myFunc becomes a plugin that can easily be invoked on elements.  So while this is similar, it's not quite the same as $.fn.myFunc.  It'd be great if you didn't have to pass an object into your function, but could just invoke it like a Jquery plugin.  I'm still looking for the right way to do this myself...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documents,

```
(function($){
  $.extend($.fn, {
    foo: function(){
      // `this` refers to the current Zepto collection.
      // When possible, return the Zepto collection to allow chaining.
      return this.html('bar')
    }
  })
})(Zepto)
```